# Is there any ways to make this code shorter?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any ways to make this code shorter?
I'm coding with jQuery.

```html
<div class="js-check-container" style="padding:0 0 0 19px;">
  <img src="/assets/admin/css/img/icon-check.svg" style="display:none;" class="js-checked">
  <img src="/assets/admin/css/img/icon-form-multi-choice-off.svg" class="js-unchecked">
</div>
```

```js
$('.js-unchecked').click(function() {
    $(this).slideUp(0);
    $(this).parent('.js-check-container').find('.js-checked').slideDown(0);
})
$('.js-checked').click(function() {
    $(this).slideUp(0);
    $(this).parent('.js-check-container').find('.js-unchecked').slideDown(0);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the same handler to both, and inside the handler, check whether the clicked element has the `js-checked` or `js-unchecked` class, from which you can generate the string to pass into `.find`.

```
$('.js-checked, .js-unchecked').click(function() {
    const justClickedChecked = this.classList.contains('js-checked);
    $(this).slideUp(0);
    $(this)
        .parent('.js-check-container')
        .find(`.js-${justClickedChecked ? 'un' : ''}checked`)
        .slideDown(0);
})
```

Comment: It worked perfectly. I'm very bigginer of programming! so thenk you so much for your answer!